# Cinnamon Desktop Installation on 18.04-How To

Tags: cinnamon

How do I install Cinnamon 4.x desktop on 18.04?

Thanks.

Comment: Cinnamon desktop 3.6 is packaged for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=cinnamon), so you'll have to go to 3rd party sources (such as PPA) which may lead to issues when you next want to release-upgrade (eg. move to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).  If you're asking for a 'howto', I'm not sure it's a good idea to go outside supported repositories (security, upgrade etc wise; ie. *you're taking on some of that responsibility yourself*).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your points are clear and well taken. I would like to follow your advice, but when I went to the URL that you recommended, it had a huge list of packages and no way to download and install them except one by one. What I need is a short script like the one in the next  answer: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cinnamon cinnamon-desktop

Comment: No the point to the packages was you can see what versions of Cinnamon are packaged with each release; if you use a 18.04 system but a later version from 3rd party (even say the 'eoan' 4.0 frpm the list I used as example) - you'll be turning parts of your 18.04 LTS with 5 year life system into a 19.10 system that EOL's middle of next year with the responsibility on you to keep it up-to-date... ie. introducing security risks... Yes you can use `ubuntu-support-status` to view your status (for packages you've added) & do it all yourself, but that's extra on you that I was trying to alert you to.

Comment: You have convinced me. Is there also anyway you can give me a short script to do it or do I have download each file separately, install separately, and then figure out ow to launch the whole?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cinnamon cinnamon-desktop
```

This will install Cinnamon desktop environment 4 (currently version 4.0.9) in Ubuntu 18.04 instead of the cinnamon-desktop-environment 3.6 package which is in the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Comment: Thank you very much.If I can't find as simple a way to install Cinnamon 3.6 (see comment to previous answer above). I have three Linux machines: one running Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME 3-which is my main machine, one running Linux Mint 19,1 (which I shall soon update to 19.2) with Cinnamon which is a "test system", and another running Ubuntu 18.04 which is a test machine and on which I shall install a version of Cinnamon to see how it goes.