# Get Windows 10 like application tray of Feren OS in GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome-shell, appmenu

I saw a video of Feren OS where there a layout of start menu exactly like Windows 10, i.e. on *Show Applications* buttons. There were application listed from A to Z in left and tiles of certain app on right (refer to [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWGvuwqKRm8&t=294s), at 4:53 timestamp).

So my question is how to disable current GNOME shell style of showing app list in ubuntu and show something like I mentioned above of Feren OS?

I am aware of showing application category from extension. Also, I know Feren OS is KDE-based and Ubuntu is not.

So I want to know GNOME-specific answer like some package, apps or scripts or terminal commands. I don't want to switch to KDE after getting so used to GNOME but I certainly need Windows 10 like menu layout.

Comment: Many of us may not be aware of FerenOS. The least you could do is to provide the link to the video you mention.

Comment: "Feren OS is a desktop Linux distribution based on Linux Mint's main edition. It ships with the Cinnamon desktop environment"  So https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188929/cinnamon-desktop-installation-on-18-04-how-to

Comment: @DKBose here is the link of video i saw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWGvuwqKRm8&t=294s. At 4:53 timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if how easy (or if possible at all) it is to get something like that in GNOME 3, but the [GNOME Shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) called [**Gno-Menu**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/608/gnomenu/) provides a pretty decent application menu.

> Gno-Menu is a traditional styled full featured Gnome-Shell apps menu, that aims to offer all the essentials in a simple uncluttered intuitive interface.
>   [image]